# Three-phase system question

Tags: three-phase

I'm solving some problems on three-phase systems. I'm doing pretty OK, but there is one problem that I'm not sure about the answer so I have some questions.

We have a three-phase circuit connected in a star connection, which is balanced (since the three impedances have the same value). The neutral wire has an impedance too, that has a value of 5 Ω and 30º. (This value it's different to the other impedances).

They're asking me the value of electric current on the neutral wire. I know it's zero when the system is balanced. However, I'm not sure if the fact of having an impedance on the neutral wire can affect on this.

I know it's a very basic question, but I'm a bit messed and I couldn't find this anywhere, thanks so much for the answers on beforehand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the system is balanced, there's no voltage from one end of the neutral to the other, so no current will flow, regardless of its impedance.

Comment: Thanks so much!!! I've got the concept much more clear now.